# Analyzing a file and counting words with Powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting

I am trying to create a script that will input a file and then have it output only the words that appear 5 or more times. this is what i came up with, but it will only print the array split into lines...thoughts?

```
clear-host 
write-host 

$file = 'file.txt' 

foreach ($word in (get-content $file))
{    
  $a = $word.split(" .,?()") 

  foreach ($occ in $a -ge 5)
  {
    ? -ge 5 (Write-Host $occ )
  }
}
```

Comment: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/josebda/2015/03/21/powershell-examples-counting-words-in-a-text-file/        should do exactly what you are wanting

Comment: thanks i will check that out!

Answer (score 0):

```
$file = "file.txt"

$contents = Get-Content -Path $file

$words = $contents.split(" .,?()") | Where-Object {$_} # this removes any empties/spaces

Write-Host "Grouped:" -ForegroundColor Cyan
$words | Group-Object

Write-Host "Filtered:" -ForegroundColor Cyan
$words | Group-Object | Where-Object Count -GE 5
```